# 502 Bad Gateway error with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_wtf' when i deploy my project to google cloud

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform

I already got wtf-form install through the pip install and it works well in my local machine. 
However, after I used wtf-form in my G-cloud, i got errors about 502 badgate and Module can not be found. 
How could i fix it?

Comment: Where in GCP are you depploying the app? (App Engine, Cloud Functions)

Comment: @JoséSoní what u mean?

Comment: Which Google Cloud Platform are you using to deploy your app?  this could be App Engine, Cloud Functions, Cloud Run , ...

Comment: @JoséSoní google app Engine. I've follow this 
 https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/quickstart

Comment: could you share the requirments.txt?

Comment: @JoséSoní i got this
    Flask==1.1.1
    gunicorn==19.9.0

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify *all* your dependencies in the `requirements.txt` file. If you're using Flask-WTF, it should have this line:

```
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
```

(or whichever version you need)